# The client need 'SUPER' privileges to the reports DB in order to create and maintain my Functions

Tags: mysql

I have problem with one of my client

Provided super privileges to the client James on  'Reports ' database , but the problem is the client need  'SUPER' privileges to the reports DB in order to create and maintain my Functions.  So I'm still unable to move forward...

BUT, I still need SUPER privileges to the reports DB in order to create and maintain my Functions.  So I'm still unable to move forward...                                 (This is what client responding , he can login but he can't create nor maintain functions on reports db server  )

After providing super privileges the client cant maintenance any of this functions nor he can create functions , how to work on this .

Comment: The `ALTER ROUTINE` privilege is needed to maintain functions.

Answer (score 1):

To modify functions and stored procedures, you need the [ALTER ROUTINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter-routine) privilege. If binary logging is enabled, you may *also* require the SUPER privilege.